# Group list elements using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python list as follows:

```
my_list = 

 [[25, 1, 0.65],
 [25, 3, 0.63],
 [25, 2, 0.62],
 [50, 3, 0.65],
 [50, 2, 0.63], 
 [50, 1, 0.62]]
```

I want to order them according to this rule:

```
1 --> [0.65, 0.62] <--25, 50
2 --> [0.62, 0.63] <--25, 50
3 --> [0.63, 0.65] <--25, 50
```

So the expected result is as follows:

```
Result = [[0.65, 0.62],[0.62, 0.63],[0.63, 0.65]]

I tried as follows:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(my_list,columns=['a','b','c'])
res = df.groupby(['b', 'c']).get_group('c')
print res

ValueError: must supply a tuple to get_group with multiple grouping keys
```

How to do it guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a pandas solution, you can sort the list by the first column, groupby the second column and covert the third column to list, if you prefer the result to be a list, use `tolist()` method afterwards:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns=list('ABC'))

s = df.sort_values('A').groupby('B').C.apply(list)

#B
#1    [0.65, 0.62]
#2    [0.62, 0.63]
#3    [0.63, 0.65]
#Name: C, dtype: object
```

The above method obtains a pandas series:

---

To get a list of lists:

```
s.tolist():
# [[0.65000000000000002, 0.62], [0.62, 0.63], [0.63, 0.65000000000000002]]
```

---

To get a numpy array of lists:

```
s.values
# array([[0.65000000000000002, 0.62], [0.62, 0.63],
#        [0.63, 0.65000000000000002]], dtype=object)

s.values[0]
# [0.65000000000000002, 0.62]          # here each element in the array is still a list
```

---

To get a 2D array or a matrix, you can transform the data frame in a different way, i.e pivot your original data frame to wide format and then convert it to a 2d array:

```
df.pivot('B', 'A', 'C').as_matrix()
# array([[ 0.65,  0.62],
#        [ 0.62,  0.63],
#        [ 0.63,  0.65]])
```

Or:

```
np.array(s.tolist())
# array([[ 0.65,  0.62],
#        [ 0.62,  0.63],
#        [ 0.63,  0.65]])
```

Comment: Any alternative for .C?

Comment: You can use `df.sort_values('A').groupby('B')['C'].apply(list)` if you mean the column names are not an unambiguous string to be used after `.`.

Comment: Ok, how can i convert the result into numpy array?

Comment: A 2D array or an array of lists?

Comment: sorry for your trouble, i am really learning about it.

Comment: I mean how to get 3D numpy array results if the results are 3d?

Comment: I don't think so. You probably need to write loops to construct 3d array from data frames.

Comment: Thank you very much. `.values` is good to me. Could you let me know alternatives of using `.apply(list)`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an other way, as it seems in your question you were trying to use `get_group()`:

```
g = [1,2,3]
result = []
for i in g:
    lst = df.groupby('b')['c'].get_group(i).tolist()
    result.append(lst)

print(result)
[[0.65, 0.62], [0.62, 0.63], [0.63, 0.65]]
```